# Emulating Google IAP headers in development

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity-aware-proxy

I'm setting Cloud Run app in GCP. I'm want to use the IAP framework. In my development environment I want to get the headers provided by the IAP. Is there a best practice for this without hardcoding?

I'm using `vscode` and docker.

I want to be able to access, among others, `X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email`

Comment: You want to simulate some headers in the requests received by your container? IAP on Cloud Run sounds strange no?

Comment: If you secure your app with IAP headers, the ID token's payload  would contains X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email. There are some code examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto#retrieving_the_user_identity). But as per the comment above, can you explain more about how you would like to use IAP in Cloud Run???

Answer (score -1):

If you secure your app with IAP headers, the ID token's payload would contain the X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email value you're looking for . There are some code examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto#retrieving_the_user_identity).

Comment: This doesn't account for local testing. Hence emulating